# Create 3 output results (rows) from one cell (Google Sheets)?

Tags: google-sheets, concatenation, google-sheets-formula

I found an issue, and I do not know if the title explains it precisely, but I somehow need to create 3 different output results (rows) based on the value in one;

I want to only enter one value in cells A2, A3, A4 (maybe have the cells merged?), the same in B2, B3, B4; C2, C3, C4 and D2, D3, D4. But in column E I need 3 output results for one value in B2.

What would be the most efficient way to do that?

Here is the sheet that I am working on:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PYPjFr3Ny_ycDJ0PEgdd3y7VAW6J32RGtqqPLDIyXQ4/edit?usp=sharing

How can I do that with one formula based on value in B2 I will get 3 output results in column E that will concatenate string "MO_MED_" with B2 and add different endings _EDITABLE, _REQUIRED, _VISIBLE?

Comment: Will the CONCATENATE() function work for you?

Comment: yes, but how can I use it to produce 3 different results?

Comment: You could have 3 formulas, all referring to B2 and each appending a different word. This is so obvious that I wonder if there is an aspect of your question that I haven't understood.

Comment: and isn't it possible to be done in only one formula? one formula to generate three results from B2 to E2, E3 and E4. Then, I would be able to expand the formula downwards and the next one would use B5 and so on :)

Comment: hmm... I used the concatenate in the second sheet and expanded all 3 formulas and it seems to work properly :) didn't know it would work that way :) this is what I wanted

Answer (score 0):

Just to make an explicit answer, the correct way to proceed here would be to use the [`CONCATENATE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094123?hl=en).

[image: Example of use]